# how to use react in Codepen with es6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, codepen

http://codepen.io/JessieZhou/pen/VPgMdP ,Here is a demo using React in CodePen, but the browser gives an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Component is not defined". However, if I insert a line "import {Component} from 'react'" in the first line, the error will be "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". Is it possible that the usage of 'class' causes this problem?

Here is my code:

```
//import {Component} from 'react'
class MyInput extends Component{
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   }

   handleChange(e){
     this.props.update(e.target.value);
   }

   render(){
     return <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text"/>
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(MyInput, document.getElementById('myinput'));
```

Here is my javascript settings in CodePen:
[javascript settings in codepen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcaMC.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reason is Component is part of React, to access that you need to use React.Component, if you directly want to use Component, then first import it from `react`, like this:

```
import {Component} from 'react';
```

Use this:

```
class MyInput extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e){
    console.log('e', e.target.vaule);
  }
  render(){
    return <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text"/>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyInput/>, document.getElementById('myinput'));
```

Check [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdYadG)

Comment: Thank you very much! Use React.Component will work, but if I want to use Component, "import {Component} from 'react'" is still not working, the error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"...

Comment: use this line in ur project, it will work, in codepen we used to use lib links, that's why we have to use complete React.Component.

Comment: Omit the import line

Comment: This is useless. It doesn't solve the 'require is not defined' error.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using import, use destructuring assignments to get React.Component. 
After adding react to codepen through js settings, it executes the script which will make React available on global scope, window.

```
const {Component} = React;
class MyInput extends Component{
    //Component code
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that `process.env.NODE_ENV` is undefined in `ReactDOM` **16.2** js file, if you import the CDN from **Quick-add**.
The solution is to use the development react and ReactDOM modules from unpkg.com:

[//unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js](http://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js)
[//unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js](http://unpkg.com/react/umd/react-dom.development.js)

There is the example works on React 16.2: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/changx03/pen/paaEyR)

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays it is possible to do direct ESM imports from Node packages to Codepen code:

```
import { default as React } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@15.4.2';
import { default as ReactDOM } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@15.4.2';
```

Answer (score 1):

Component is a subclass of react. So either you import it or use `React.Component`
During render you have to use jsx
`MyInput` wont work. `<MyInput/>` will work

```
class MyInput extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.props.update(e.target.value);
  }
  render(){
    return <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text"/>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyInput/>, document.getElementById('myinput'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `class MyInput extends React.Component` or switch to [Webpackbin](http://www.webpackbin.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much~ I will try Webpackbin later~

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend `React.Component`, not just `Component`.

And you have to render `<MyInput />` instead of `MyInput`.

Try this instead

```
class MyInput extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.props.update(e.target.value);
  }
  render(){
    return <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text"/>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyInput />, document.getElementById('myinput'));
```